# SSIS Execute process task to copy 2 files into new file

Tags: sql-server, cmd, ssis, etl, executeprocesstask

Hi i wanted to copy the records of two csv files into a new file.

Task : Copy A + B into C

```
 OR Copy A to B ( this is what i am doing but i don't know how via SSIS)
```

I used SSIS to do so using Execute Process Task . In order to verify i tried it in command prompt. 
[image]

When i tried via SSIS package it fails i am not sure why here are the inputs for the executable and the arguement. 
[image]

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `CMD.exe` requires either `/k` or `/c` for non interactive use. See `cmd /?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommendations:**

- Don't use \ when assigning a value (only in expressions)
- You have to use /C before passing parameters to cmd.exe
- Because you didn't specify the Working directory you should provide the full path for each file, if not `Out.csv` will be created in the package runtime folder.

The command must be like the following:

```
/C copy /b C:\Temp\Source.csv + C:\Temp\Destination.csv C:\Temp\Out.csv
```

**Reference**

- [Executing Command Prompt commands in SSIS](https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/executing-msdos-commands-in-ssis/)

Comment: Thank you very much i didn't though about /c